# Add and Remove a css image class on toggle using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle the menu when the user clicks the artcile's h3 element, much like an accordion but a little different.

What I am unable to achieve is that the image does not display nor does it change when the element's slideToggle function is called. However, the slideToggle is working fine, it is just the image I need assistance with.

HTML:-

```
<div class="pages">
    <article class="collapsible expanded collapsed">
        <h3><?php echo $lang->xlate('presentation-b');?></h3>
    </article>

    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <?php echo $lang->xlate('presentation-c');?> </li>



            <li>
                <?php echo $lang->xlate('presentation-d');?> </li>



            <li>
                <?php echo $lang->xlate('presentation-e');?> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#paragraph .pages .collapsible {
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#paragraph .pages .collapsible .expanded  {background: url('../img/list.png') no-repeat left top;}
#paragraph .pages .collapsible .collapsed {background: url('../img/pagination.gif') no-repeat left top;}
```

jQuery:-

```
        $('.collapsible').click(function(){
        $coll = $(this);
        $content = $coll.next();
        $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
         //execute this after slideToggle is done
         //change text of header based on visibility of content div
                    if($(this).hasClass('expanded'))
                    {
                        $(this).toggleClass('collapsed expanded');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).toggleClass('expanded collapsed');
                    } 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need the class indicator  `"."`  when adding or removing classes. This means that you are not toggling the background image for each state.

```
$(this).addClass('.collapsed').removeClass('.expanded');
```

so your code should be

```
if ($(this).hasClass('.expanded')) {
    $(this).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
} else {
    $(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed');
}
```

Comment: I edited the question after removing the `.` and made the necessary changes but the image does not display.

Comment: check your scope of "$(this)" - is it affecting $coll or $content (it should be affecting $coll - to ensure that the old element collapses when the new one opens) - you might need to change it to ...if($coll.hasClass('expanded')...

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.` before class name on adding and removing classes.

```
$(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed');
```

Also you can use `toggleClass()` to toggle between classes.

```
$(this).toggleClass('collapsed expanded');
```

like :

```
$('.collapsible').click(function() {
    $coll = $(this);
    $content = $coll.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $(this).toggleClass('collapsed expanded');
    });
});
```

Comment: I edited the question after removing the `.` and made the necessary changes but the image does not display.